# Connect Apache Spark with IPFS

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, distributed-computing, ipfs

I am aware that we can connect with specified nodes of the network using IPFS.

But what I want is that I want to connect to only specified or some authorized nodes to share data with only those specific nodes.

Using Spark and IPFS for processing data on the specified machine on the Internet.

How is this achieved?

If there's appropriate samples or link that would be helpful for me to work on a prototype.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a private swarm where IPFS nodes *only connect to other peers who have a shared secret key*:

https://github.com/ipfs/go-ipfs/blob/v0.4.20/docs/experimental-features.md#private-networks